# When did Dick Grayson leave Batman?

Tags: dc, batman

Which issue to be specific? I can't find the scene when Dick Grayson decided to leave Batman

Answer (score 2):

Well, according to the dubious Wikipedia.

> Nightwing: Secret Files & Origins #1 and Nightwing: Year One tell the full post-Crisis version of how Dick Grayson gives up his identity as Robin (having been "fired" by Batman). - [Nightwing, Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publication_history_of_Dick_Grayson#Nightwing)

Comment: Maybe I should edit my question to where was Dick Grayson last appearance before he became the Nightwing.